# Given the matrix $A$, find $r(AA^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\
2&4\\
0&0\\
\lambda&1
\end{pmatrix}$.
Find the rank of $(AA^T)$ with respect to $\lambda$.

$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&0&\lambda\\
2&4&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$

$AA^T=\begin{pmatrix}
5&10&0&\lambda+2\\
10&20&0&2\lambda+4\\
0&0&0&0\\
\lambda+2&2\lambda+4&0&\lambda^2+1
\end{pmatrix}$

What should I do now? The first 3 columns are linearly dependent, right?

Comment: $\mathrm{rank}(AA^{\top})=\mathrm{rank}(A)$.

Comment: Yes, they're linearly dependent since they're all multiples of the first column.

Comment: $\text{rank} (AA^T) = \text{rank}(A) =  1$ for $\lambda=1/2$, and the rank is $2$ for $\lambda \neq 1/2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The OP hasn't said that the underlying field is real (although I do believe that it is real).

Comment: @user1551 Whenever there is lack of specification/rigour in the question, you tend to assume things.

Comment: The usage of numbers other than $0$ and $1$ indicates that the underlying field does not have characteristic $2$. Therefore the multiplicative inverse of $2$ exists and Alex' solution holds.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier $AA^T$ and $A$ need not have the same rank over finite fields

Comment: @ReinhardMeier for example, take this matrix over $\Bbb F_5$ with $\lambda = -2$

Comment: You are right, I focused too much on the rank of $A$ and forgot to consider the matrix multiplication.